# Can we please make this deleted not-an-answer a comment instead?

Tags: support, convert-to-comment

I received an answer that should have been a comment on this question: [How do I display a PDF using PdfSharp in ASP.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121876/how-do-i-display-a-pdf-using-pdfsharp-in-asp-net-mvc) I flagged it as not an answer, and a mod deleted the answer.

The user who posted the answer is very new (19 rep) and didn't have the ability to post comments when they wrote the answer. Moreover, before their post was deleted, I was able to have a productive conversation with them that would have been very appropriate as a comment thread. Can we please be nice to them and move their not-an-answer to being a comment? I wrote an answer to my own question where the comments would make sense.

Comment: "deleted by Kirk Woll, Aशwini चhaudhary, Soner Gönül 9 hours ago" <-- not deleted by a mod.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was deleted by the community (3 different users), not a moderator.

It's not appropriate as a comment, as you can see:

[image: not a comment]

This user has a question based off your issue.  Comments aren't for conversations, they're for clarification on the OP's issue. In this case, they had a 1v1 support session going on with you *for their issue*, and that's not what Stack Overflow comments (or answers) are for.

The deletion was appropriate. You can always see if this user is available through their profile, and contact them if you wish, but no, this should not be converted to a comment.