# Privilege to convert deleted answer to comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers, privileges

I came across a deleted answer that I thought would make a good comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23589272/608639.

I think it would have made a good comment because it was a one or two line answer *and* it included a reference to a bug report. The bug report was not present in the other answers.

I believe I can flag it, but I'm hesitant to do it because it creates more work for someone else.

Is there a privilege to convert a deleted answer to a comment? Or is there a process that does not burden diamond mods?

Related: [Converting answers into comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256250/converting-answers-into-comments), but it has no answers.

[Can we please make this deleted not-an-answer a comment instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251520/can-we-please-make-this-deleted-not-an-answer-a-comment-instead) discusses similar.

Comment: You could leave a comment yourself saying like “As Jane mentioned in [her deleted answer] *(that’d be a link)*, you may want to see [this bug report] *(another link)*.”