# Shouldn't this answer be converted into a comment or just deleted?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers, disputed-flags

I today found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379143/1983854) that exactly says:

> 30 seconds of googeling:
>   http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html

I flagged it as "low quality post" because I thought it should be moved into a comment, or directly deleted. To me, it is a [just link answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

The flag is marked as disputed by tight difference [on the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5564446) (4 recommend deletion / 3 looks OK), but I still think it should be deleted. Am I right?

Comment: Just as an FYI, posts with a lot of upvotes but disputed reviews (look good/recommend deletion) go into a separate mod queue for us to review.  At that point, we will determine if the post gets deleted.  The review queue can't delete positively scored content.

Comment: Oh, you do magic, now it is deleted! Sorry to make you work twice, I wasn't aware of it @bluefeet

Comment: Is that question now really more likely to help people since the answer was deleted?

Comment: @sth, the code behind the link in that answer was flawed in the first place. So yes, people are less likely to be bitten, and therefore more likely to be helped.

Comment: @sth Yeah. "30 seconds of Googleing" is not useful in any fashion. Presumably, a future reader would arrive at that answer.... by Google. What utility is it to anyone, anywhere, to discover via Google that one needs to Google for the answer?

Comment: @Chris: The answer doesn't say "go to google", it says "here's the solution I found". The utility of a link pointing to a solution seems obvious to me.

Comment: @sth It comes across as rude, and if it didn't have the extra information from the link in the answer itself, that's why it's not that useful. The link could quite easily go dead. So if it went dead, no one had edited the information in, and it wasn't deleted, then what use would it be to future readers?

Comment: @sth If a future visitor found that question through Google, isn't it likely they've also found that search result? The entire answer is operating on the premise that the OP did not look. In fact, the OP may have looked -- it turns out the solution isn't even valid. It isn't useful, and it further presumes bad faith (failure to research) on the part of every person who reads it in the future, even though they would likely encounter that page by researching. There's no amount of debate between you and I that will make that snarky posting of a link to bad code useful, end of story.

Comment: @Kendra: What use will it be to future readers if it is deleted? Of course the link *might* go bad and the answer might become useless by that, but deleting it makes it useless immediately. The rude tone of the answer would be much better removed by editing.

Comment: @Chris: Who knows exactly they googled for and which results they got/looked at. And for technical problems with the answer: isn't that what votes/comments are for? The slight rudeness in the question certainly isn't appropriate and should be edited out, but I didn't think that's what this flag was about. If people really feel strongly about that they should just flag as "offensive".

Comment: @sth -- exactly, who knows? So how do you justify the usefulness of posting an answer concerning how long it took to find an article on the subject using Google? Or to post only the first result of a Google search related to the question as an answer without testing or otherwise commenting or event *mentioning* the code contained at the other end of the link? You're here trying to make the case that deleting the answer did not benefit the community, but you aren't making it. People **did** flag it, and it was deleted, not only because of the tone but also because link-only answers are useless.

Comment: @ sth - yes, we need a flag for "convert to comment". Also see [Privilege to convert deleted answer to comment?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268820/privilege-to-convert-deleted-answer-to-comment).

Comment: @Chris: It seems that lots of people found it helpful and upvoted. Without having really looked into the subject I assume you can fairly easily create a good implementation from the linked code and the upvoted comment. But more generally, I just don't agree with the idea that a deleted answer is somehow more useful than an answer with a link to helpful content.

Comment: @sth It is called editorial oversight, and it happens everywhere, all day, every day. Especially on sites like this. The idea is quality over quantity, as you are well aware. If you think link-only answers with snarky comments about how long it took to use Google are useful, avoid the review queue until you come back to your senses. You know better, why have this debate? Playing devils advocate for the fun? "HRRR use Google" is help-forum fodder.

Comment: @chris: I don't really care about this specific case. The problem is that generally all answers that point to external solutions get deleted. If the answer uses completely unoffensive language and points to an external solution that works and was found by other means than google and whatnot it's usually deleted just the same, from what I've seen. I think that makes the content on SO worse, not better. I think thats bad. The snarkyness and the references to Google are not really relevant, they could easily be edited, but the resulting answer would likely be deleted anyway because "link-only".

Comment: @sth The simple reason is link rot, and there's an exhaustive discussion of the rest of the nuances of the subject over at [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Avoiding common help-forum tropes is a large driver of these kinds of policies. I don't know about you, but by level 6 I was about to let Princess Toadstool work things out for herself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This answer was reviewed in the low quality and the result was mixed *Recommend Deletion × 4, Looks OK × 3*, it also was highly upvoted with 35 upvotes / 20 downvotes.

When posts have a controversial review like this "*more delete votes than 'looks good'*", the system raises an automatic flag for the moderators to review the disputed content.  Moderators have a separate review queue specifically for the disputed stuff and at that point we will decide if it will be removed.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question *" I still think it should be deleted. Am I right?"*

Comment: @TJ Well the answer was deleted by a mod when it was reviewed, so it was determined that yes it needed to be removed.

Answer (score 7):

Being that a moderator deleted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379143/703717) - it seems clear that you were right.