# Convert answer to comment

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers, not-an-answer, convert-to-comment

I have heard of converting answers on questions to comments, but this seems to be a moderator personal choice? I have [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605868/rails-controller-testing-gem) that got an answer asking what version I was running. I flagged it, since it was a comment but not an answer to the question, however the moderators deleted it rather than converting. It would have been a relevant comment. Is there a way to flag an answer specifically as something that should be a comment? The flag feature leaves no way to add details or to respond to the moderator(s) decision.

Comment: Maybe you should've put up the answer on your question yourself? with a link to the useful user's profile?

Comment: I did edit the question with the answer, but I don't understand the decision to completely delete the request for clarification. I didn't think to link to the user given the assumption that the content wouldn't be deleted. The user who made the comment deserves (in my opinion) recognition for having asked about the version number in the form of an upvote-able comment.

Comment: don't edit the answer in a question. Post it as an answer. In any case, what flag did you use on the comment? (and comments aren't meant to be permanent in Stack, they are secondary (even quartenary) citizens)

Comment: Why would I post the version number of something as an answer? It isn't an answer to my original question, it is a clarification of information relevant to the question. I have always seen this done as an edit so that future readers of the question have that information up-front. I flagged it a "not an answer" since it was a question in regards to my question, and not a solution.

As for comments not being a permanent thing, that gets at my question. I've always been thrown off by this notion, as they are part of the history of a question.

Comment: OH. OOOOOH..... wow, I'm tired. I read your question upside down. I thought someone gave you an ANSWER in a comment, not the opposite. Now this whole thing makes a lot more sense.  And yeah, when you flag as "not an answer", it's likely it'll be deleted (when you flag NAA, it is sent in a review queue, where the only thing available to people reviewing is to delete or not delete. It's not sent to our mods). In any case, editing was the correct thing, disregard my previous message

Comment: And to answer the "comments are part of the history of a question".... now that your version number is edited in your question, why does the comment need to stay up?

Comment: No problem :)

I was unaware that some flags didn't go to mods (I was aware of votes to close, etc, but I though flags all went to mods).

There is no distinct reason that the comment is necessary, and the edit has a description explaining what was changed (though in this case it is very obvious from the diff), however I always thought of the comments as being saved with the rest of the question. I'm curious the philosophy regarding comments, since it is clearly different from my own.

Comment: Basically, anything that isn't spam or custom flag is sent to review queues, not mods. The way I understand them, comments (not the same on meta) are meant as clarifications for a question. Basically exactly like your case. Once the clarification is in the edit of the question, why would you need it?

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm asking about something that was deleted when I expected it to be converted.

Comment: How about this? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251520/can-we-please-make-this-deleted-not-an-answer-a-comment-instead

Comment: Relevant, and answers the review queue vs moderator part of the question, however it is a different case where the answer (as noted in the correct answer in that link) wasn't appropriate as a comment either.

Aside from the discussion on why comments are not needed once and edit is made, the answer in my case was relevant and appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the flag menu, the correct option for flagging something that should be a comment is "not an answer":

> **not an answer** This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a
>   comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

As you can see, one of the options here is that the answer should be a comment.

I think in this case you did exactly the right thing by editing the requested version number into your question. Once the question was updated with the requested information, nothing is lost by deleting the answer (there's no need to convert it to a comment, since that comment would immediately be obsolete).

If this had instead been somebody else's question where somebody had asked "What is the version number?" in an answer and the OP had responded as a comment "0.0.3" but hadn't updated their question with this information, I would either leave a comment asking them to edit that into their question or I would edit it into the question myself (in your case by making a suggested edit).

Comment: "or deleted altogether".  That's what happened.  If he wants it turned into a comment then he has to say so with a custom flag.

Comment: @HansPassant is spot on about my issue. I ended up selecting not an answer, which got it deleted, but is accurate, however I would have needed to use a custom flag to save it as a comment, apparently.

Comment: Ironically THIS answer is not an answer to the question since it's exactly what the OP did that got the answer deleted!