# New queue/feature/option to convert answers to comments and vice-versa

Tags: discussion, feature-request, not-an-answer, comment-flags, convert-to-comment

I've seen many answers that should be comments, as they're either too short and don't explain anything or just hint at the answer but can be helpful. There are many comments that should be answers and answers that should be comments.

Can we have a review queue to convert comments flagged as answers and answers flagged as comments?

For converting answers to comments, we can either:

1. have an option while submitting an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (besides the "Save edits"?), if the edited version doesn't exceed the comment's character limit (and not accepted and more than 30 days old?), to delete the answer and post it as a comment on behalf of the answerer
2. have an option to choose between "Convert to comment" and "Delete altogether"/"Leave it to the reviewer" after selecting NAA

For converting comments to answers, we can have an option to flag it as "It should be an answer", which can be followed by options to "Improve and convert to an answer" and "Convert to an answer".

This isn't a duplicate of [Convert answer to comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296411/convert-answer-to-comment).

Answer (score 16):

I vote no.

### Reviewer Time

First and foremost, a new queue is going to take reviewer time. [We already struggle to have enough reviewers on a regular basis to handle the current review task load.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416108/15497888) Adding *another* review queue only splits reviewer time further. Reviewer (and moderator) time is a finite resource, and we really have to consider how we use it.

#### Incorporating into an existing Queue

Assuming we added another option to the existing [Low quality answers queue](/help/review-low-quality), the queue that currently handles NAA/VLQ flags, then we have issues reaching a consensus. Currently, the post is deleted with 3 delete votes (assuming score <=0) or 4 Recommend deletions. Adding an additional option will increase review times. Consider a post where 3 users choose to recommend deletion and one chooses to convert to comment. Under the current system the task would have been completed as the user who chose to convert to a comment would have chosen to recommend deletion, while under the new system the task needs to hang until there's a consensus (at least one additional review task).

### Answers to comments

[Moderators already have the ability to convert answers to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74160/1099857). If something is *really* worth preserving an "in need of moderator intervention" flag can be used, though in my experience most of these are not worth saving. As "they're either too short and don't explain anything or just hint at the answer"

Something else to consider is there are *significant* features that are missing for normal users to be able to handle this operation well. The ability for moderators to edit comments is *extremely* helpful when making this conversion. If users are allowed to convert to comments either the post already needs to be formatted appropriately to be an acceptable comment, or the edit needs to be made *before* the post is converted. (This is an issue if we add the option to LQA because an Edit would kick the task out of review and then not be able to be considered for comment conversion).

We also [already have a trivial answer mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/1099857) which already handles converting the most trivial of answers posted on the site.

#### Circumventing reputation

The incentive structure we have allows users to earn privileges as they ask and answer questions that are well received by the community. Converting answers to comments for users [< 50 reputation](/help/privileges/comment) allows users without the privilege to comment if they answer poorly enough. Additionally, it mitigates the community's ability to vote on their content appropriately. A low quality answer would normally attract downvotes and contribute to a post-ban, however, this would not be possible once the post was deleted and is not possible on comments at all.

### Comments to answers

#### Answer quality

Most answers in the comments are *not* high quality. They include only the mini-markdown formatting available in comments, and they are extremely limited in their scope. While it is possible to provide a trivial answer, a one-liner with no explanation, or a solid guiding question or comment: these are not high quality answers. While there are certainly exceptions to this rule, by the nature of the comment restrictions alone the majority of these converted answers would be of lower quality than a well written answer.

#### Just write an answer

The "improve and convert to an answer" option is tricky. This is likely to require a subject-matter expert to be able to make quality technical improvements needed to flesh out a comment into a complete answer. So in that regard, people who are able to "improve and convert to an answer" can probably also just write a good answer themselves. This is also very commonly done. Give [credit to the user](/help/referencing) and then build out a high quality answer that benefits the community. If the comment *really* is a good answer on its own [a community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/15497888) can be created to avoid earning reputation from someone else's idea.

#### Reputation exposure

Converting a comment to an answer provides reputation exposure contrary to the intent of the comment author. Many people provide comments because they either cannot or do not want to provide a more complete answer. I think it is also problematic to turn a transient short message into a more permanent post that is capable of receiving both up **and down** votes, especially on the scale of a review queue, without the post authors consent.

### Flag (mis)use

Last, but not least, people flag things incorrectly **all the time**. Mods spend a fair amount of time declining flags that are being used incorrectly. I can't imagine the workload of "this comment worked for me make it an answer" type flags that would be received.

Comment: +1, but why not try it? I'm aware that moderators have the option to convert them and that I can answer them, but- moderators don't look through all posts... If a comment is really that good, it can be made an answer, right?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder No, although I've often wished I *could* convert comments to answers, we cannot (only answers to comments).  I'd be okay with this as a moderator-only feature, but I don't think general availability would be wise, for the reasons Henry has discussed.

Comment: Actually, the thing I most frequently want to convert to answers are suggested edits.  Many of them completely rewrite the answer, and the result is a good answer...just very much not the one that the original answerer wrote, and so it's rejected for conflicting with the intent.